# How to get the volumeid for the device mounted at /dev/sdf for a particular instance with aws cli?

Tags: aws-cli

I am trying to get the volume id of the device mounted at /dev/sdf to a particular instance.

Command:
    aws ec2  describe-volumes --filters Name=attachment.instance-id,Values=$instance_id_main --region us-west-2 --output json

Output:

```
{
    "Volumes": [
        {
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-west-2a", 
            "Attachments": [
                {
                    "AttachTime": "2017-06-15T12:59:18.000Z", 
                    "InstanceId": "i-073cfdf5832e5a7ab", 
                    "VolumeId": "vol-096ca253d37b3e42b", 
                    "State": "attached", 
                    "DeleteOnTermination": false, 
                    "Device": "/dev/sdf"
                }
            ], 
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Value": "NewVolume", 
                    "Key": "Name"
                }
            ], 
            "Encrypted": false, 
            "VolumeType": "gp2", 
            "VolumeId": "vol-096ca253d37b3e42b", 
            "State": "in-use", 
            "Iops": 100, 
            "SnapshotId": "", 
            "CreateTime": "2017-06-15T12:39:06.687Z", 
            "Size": 5
        }, 
        {
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-west-2a", 
            "Attachments": [
                {
                    "AttachTime": "2017-06-15T12:57:46.000Z", 
                    "InstanceId": "i-073cfdf5832e5a7ab", 
                    "VolumeId": "vol-0189e6a20392bb709", 
                    "State": "attached", 
                    "DeleteOnTermination": true, 
                    "Device": "/dev/sda1"
                }
            ], 
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Value": "NewTesting", 
                    "Key": "Name"
                }
            ], 
            "Encrypted": false, 
            "VolumeType": "gp2", 
            "VolumeId": "vol-0189e6a20392bb709", 
            "State": "in-use", 
            "Iops": 100, 
            "SnapshotId": "snap-0a642b1f5be55819a", 
            "CreateTime": "2017-06-15T12:57:46.027Z", 
            "Size": 8
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried with --query option of describe volume given in the example then I got below output.

Command:

```
aws ec2  describe-volumes --filters Name=attachment.instance-id,Values=$instance_id_main --query 'Volumes[*].{ID:VolumeId,Tag:Tags}' --region us-west-2 --output json

[
    {
        "Tag": [
            {
                "Value": "NewVolume", 
                "Key": "Name"
            }
        ], 
        "ID": "vol-096ca253d37b3e42b"
    }, 
    {
        "Tag": [
            {
                "Value": "NewTesting", 
                "Key": "Name"
            }
        ], 
        "ID": "vol-0189e6a20392bb709"
    }
]
```

Then I tried to get the Attachments and I got below error.

Command:

```
aws ec2  describe-volumes --filters Name=attachment.instance-id,Values=$instance_id_main --query 'Volumes[*].{Attachments:Device[*]}' --region us-west-2 --output text
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "Attachments": null
    }, 
    {
        "Attachments": null
    }
]
```

Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
die() { status=$1; shift; echo "FATAL: $*"; exit $status; }
EC2_INSTANCE_ID="`wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id || die \"wget instance-id has failed: $?\"`"
EC2_AWSAVZONE=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone)
EC2_REGION=${EC2_AWSAVZONE::-1}

DATA_VOLUME_ID="`aws ec2 describe-volumes  --filters Name=attachment.device,Values=/dev/sdf Name=attachment.instance-id,Values=$EC2_INSTANCE_ID --query 'Volumes[*].{ID:VolumeId}' --region $EC2_REGION --output text`"

echo $DATA_VOLUME_ID
```

Output:

```
vol-096ca253d37b3e42b
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method using describe-instances

```
#query using instance name
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].BlockDeviceMappings[?DeviceName==`/dev/sdf`].[Ebs.VolumeId]' --filters Name=tag:Name,Values=${INSTANCE_NAME} --output=text

#query using instance-id
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids ${INSTANCE_ID} --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].BlockDeviceMappings[?DeviceName==`/dev/sdf`].[Ebs.VolumeId]' --output=text
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on [Nitro](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/nitro/) you can use the `ebsnvme-id` utility to get the volume ID from a device like this:

```
awk '{print $3'} < <(/sbin/ebsnvme-id  --volume /dev/nvme1n1)
```

Bonus:

You can get the device mounted at a specific mountpoint with findmnt like this:

```
findmnt -noheadings --output SOURCE --target /mnt/foo
```

Put all this together, and you can get the EBS Volume ID of the volume mounted at `/mnt/foo` like this:

```
awk '{print $3}' < <(
  /sbin/ebsnvme-id  --volume "$(
    findmnt -noheadings --output SOURCE --target /mnt/foo
  )"
)
```